# Reading N lines from a file in java?

Tags: java, arrays, file, java.util.scanner, bufferedreader

I am not quite sure how to explain my question but I will try my best. Say for example, I have a file containing 100 numbers, is it possible to read lines 25-50 from this 100 numbers file.

To read N amount from begining, I would do something like this;

```
ArrayList<Double> array = new ArrayList<Double>();
 Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("numbers.txt"));
 int counter = 0;
 while(input.hasNextLine() && counter < 10)
 {
     array.add(Double.parseDouble(input.nextLine()));
     counter++;
 }
```

But I am not quite sure how I can go about start reading from a given line e.g. lines 25-50 or  25-75 or 75-100 etc.

Any help is much appreciated and please let me know if my question is not clear.

edit:

Some data in the file:

- 1.45347,1.1545,1.2405
- 1.467,1.4554,1.2233
- 1.4728,1.3299,1.1532
- 1.131,1.5139,1.0044
- 1.4614,1.7373,1.6235
- 1.654,1.5544,1.61147

Comment: Does each line contain one number?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question, each line contains 3 set of numbers separated by comma. for example; 1.4352,1.1749,1.5531

Comment: You cant start reading from midway.you'll have to start from begining,read,but store nothing & as line 25 comes start storing/using the values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
byte[] inputBytes = "line 1\nline 2\nline 3\ntok 1 tok 2".getBytes();
Reader r = new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(inputBytes));

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(r);
Scanner s = new Scanner(br);

System.out.println("First line:  " + br.readLine());
System.out.println("Second line: " + br.readLine());
System.out.println("Third line:  " + br.readLine());

System.out.println("Remaining tokens:");
while (s.hasNext())
    System.out.println(s.next());
```

and add a while loop like Astra suggested

Answer (score 3):

Using Java 8 you have an easy solution. Note that the below code does not make any bounds checking of any kind (this is left as an exercise):

```
private static final Pattern COMMA = Pattern.compile(",");

public static List<Double> readNumbers(final String file, 
    final int startLine, final int endLine)
    throws IOException
{
    final long skip = (long) (startLine - 1);
    final long limit = (long) (endLine - startLine);
    final Path path = Paths.get(file);

    try (
        final Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    ) {
        return stream.skip(skip).limit(limit)
            .flatMap(COMMA::splitAsStream)
            .map(Double::valueOf)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

---

It also appears that the problem is unclear; the code above reads all doubles in a given line range. If what you want is to read all doubles from a given start "index" to a given end "index", all you have to do in the code above is change the placement of the `.skip().limit()` to after the `.map()`.

Comment: Hi fge, what do you mean by bounds, and thanks for your answer.

Comment: Well, I don't check whether start is less than end and stuff like that. Also, see post edit.

Comment: I can make the change of checking whether start is less then end. Thanks, it is working for what I need. Thanks again. Only problem being is that its for 1.8, which will do for now but at times I am force to work with lower versions of java like 1.6 and 1.7, therefore I will need to try and adapt this.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have multiple numbers (unknown number of numbers) on each line:

```
int start = 25;
int n finish = 50;
String delimit = ",";
List<Double> array = new ArrayList<Double>(finish - start);
 Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("numbers.txt"));
 int counter = 1;
 while(input.hasNextLine() && counter <= finish)
 {

        String line = input.nextLine();
        String[] splits = line.split(delimit);
        for (int i=0; i<splits.length; i++){
           if (counter >= start && counter <=finish){
               array.add(Double.parseDouble(splits[i]));
            }
            counter++;
         }
 }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, I will give it a try. but the file I have contains 3 set of numbers on each line. e.g. 1.4352,1.1749,1.5531

Comment: @Henry, that is important, what is the delimiter, eg comma? space? is it like 23.34, 265.76, 93.7? provide an example (always provide an example of data)

Comment: Sorry I didn't give an example, the data is separated by comma only, no spaces e.g. 1.664,1.3844,1.2133

Comment: @Henry, updated answer. You can have any number of numbers on a line

Comment: Astra, its not reading line by line, instead it reads number by number e.g. instead of reading line 25, it separates each double by a comma and reads 25th double number.

Comment: Wait, so, what do you want? All doubles from a given line range or doubles within a given range? That is not quite the same thing

Comment: I want it to read each line, instead of each individual double.